# Questions on proper REST api design specifically on the PUT action when updating a resource

Tags: rest, http, put

I'm creating a REST interface (aren't we all), and I want to UPDATE a resource.

So, I think to use a PUT.

So, i read [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6).

My take away is that i PUT to a URL like this

```
/hc/api/v1/organizer/event/762d36c2-afc5-4c51-84eb-9b5b0ef2990c
```

with a payload, then a permanent redirect to the URL that it can GET an updated version of the resource.
In this case it happens to be the same URL, different action.

So my questions are:

1. Is my understanding of updating a resource correct in using a PUT, and is my understanding of the use of the PUT correct.
2. When a client gets a redirect does it do the same action on the redirected URL as it did on the original URL?  If its "depends" is there a standard most clients follow?

I ask the 2nd question, because POSTMAN and my JQuery AJAX calls are choking.  JQuery because of net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.  So is it redirecting and trying the PUT again, which it will get another REDIRECT?

curl blows up too but even though it says if it gets a 301 it will switch to a GET, it doesn't really seem to do that when i look at the output (below).

**When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request using the same unmodified method.**

CURL OUTPUT (edited for brevity) (also note how it says its going to switch to a GET [incorrectly from a POST], but then it seems to do a PUT anyway):

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Basic AUTHZ==" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: e80657f0-a8f5-af77-1d9d-d7bc22ed0b30" -d '{ JSONDATA"}' http://localhost:8080/hc/api/v1/organizer/event/762d36c2-afc5-4c51-84eb-9b5b0ef2990c -v -L
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> PUT /hc/api/v1/organizer/event/762d36c2-afc5-4c51-84eb-9b5b0ef2990c HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic AUTHZ==
> Content-Type: application/json
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Postman-Token: e80657f0-a8f5-af77-1d9d-d7bc22ed0b30
> Content-Length: 203
>
* upload completely sent off: 203 out of 203 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
< Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/hc; Max-Age=0; Expires=Fri, 20-Feb-2015 03:53:28 GMT
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=uwI3_41LAa7vlvapTsrZdw10.macbook-air; path=/hc
* Server WildFly/8 is not blacklisted
< Server: WildFly/8
< Location: /hc/api/v1/organizer/event/762d36c2-afc5-4c51-84eb-9b5b0ef2990c
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sat, 21 Feb 2015 03:53:28 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://localhost:8080/hc/api/v1/organizer/event/762d36c2-afc5-4c51-84eb-9b5b0ef2990c'
* Switch from POST to GET
* Found bundle for host localhost: 0x7f9e4b415430
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> PUT /hc/api/v1/organizer/event/762d36c2-afc5-4c51-84eb-9b5b0ef2990c HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic dGVzdHVzZXIxOlBhc3N3b3JkMQ==
> Content-Type: application/json
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Postman-Token: e80657f0-a8f5-af77-1d9d-d7bc22ed0b30
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=fDXxlH2xI-0-DEaC6Dj5EhD9.macbook-air; path=/hc
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 8593
< Date: Sat, 21 Feb 2015 03:53:28 GMT
<
```

...failure ensues...  It actually does a PUT

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would the location move? It doesn't, so why "Moved Permanatly". The client knows the exact URL, and it doesn't change. No need to set Location header or redirect. This is mainly for POST, when you _create_ a resource. And the redirect pattern, as far as I know isn't really a rest practice, but  more a web practice, to avoid repeated submissions. Basically what you are doing is an infinite loop. You PUT, redirect back to the same resource, which redirects back to the same resource, which redirects back to the same resource...

Comment: I take back the last part about being an infinite loop. A redirect should GET. But in this case their should be no need for a redirect, that's pretty much the point I'm making

Comment: right it didn't make sense, i was reading it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're reading too much into the 301 redirect section.

If you want to update a resource using PUT, return:

- 201: if the resource was created
- 200: with the updated resource

The 301 in question only applies if there actually is a redirect in question - like, if something can be identified by name, and you need to redirect it to a url that has the id or something.  (Maybe you refactor and people are still consuming the old endpoint).

So, do you really need to redirect your PUT requests?  Because you should be sending back the updated resource within the same loop using 200, like stated above, instead of "redirecting to GET".

EDIT: Fix some spelling.

Comment: i was reading too much into it, in fact the way it was paragraphed, i thought "it must..." was a bullet point on the spec and didn't notice it was actually a continuation of the sentence before.