# REST PUT create or update

Tags: rest, http, put

I want to create or update an item in one go with the following request:

```
PUT /items/{id}
```

Should I return `201 Created` if the item has been created and `204 No Content` when it has been updated? Or should I return the same status for both actions?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/28642061/1848654 you should return `200 OK` and the new resource after an update.

Comment: Thanks, in that answer irisius say: `201` if created and `200` with the updated resource if updated. So two different responses depending on the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Use `200 OK` in both cases if the distinction isn't important to clients.

Use `201 Created` upon creation, and `200 OK` upon update, if the distinction is important.

## Details

With RESTful design, there's no single, correct way of doing things, but I've often found that the [original HTTP status code specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) provides good guidance.

It's always fine to return `200 OK` if you don't expect the client to take separate action based on the response, but you *can* provide more information if you think the client is going to need it. Just be aware that clients may come to *expect* that of your API, so once you start providing more details, you can't easily change your mind.

That said, if you want to return `201 Created`, then according to the specification:

> The response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate.

As an example, you can put the location in the `Location` header, but you can also put it in the body of the response (but then you must document the structure and content-type of that body).

When it comes to `204 No Content` responses, [they create dead ends for link-following clients](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/30/rest-lesson-learned-avoid-204-responses), so if you're creating a [true level 3 REST API](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) then you should avoid that response type as a courtesy to clients.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is clearly stated in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), section 9.6:

*If a new resource is created, the origin server MUST inform the user agent via the 201 (Created) response. If an existing resource is modified, either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate successful completion of the request.*